# Is there an interior bathroom filter made to exhaust filtered air back into room?

Tags: plumbing-fixture

I have a bathroom in the basement that has an exhaust fan but it doesn't go anywhere.  I need a filter on it to clear/clean the air and moister.

Comment: Where does it go?  Would you correct spelling?  Post a picture?

Comment: Are you asking for somebody to provide a link to a specific product, or are you asking how you should properly exhaust your bathroom?

Answer (score 2):

A bathroom fan needs to vent to the outside, so as to actually remove moisture effectively.

While you could cobble something up with a dehumdifier, there's no good reason to, and plenty of good reasons not to; Which is why you won't find that for sale anywhere.

Comment: +1 Depending on your location, venting to the outside may actually be required by code.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes it does. The damp air is being pulled up into the area above the ceiling. This is likely to end up causing water damage in that area (like to the roof sheathing). That's why bathroom fans are vented to the outside. Look up venting a bath fan on the web: you should find plenty of info to help you.

Answer (score -1):

A dehumidifer does some air filtering, though not enough for odor removal which is one of the best reasons for an air exhaust.

A electrostatic air cleaner might be up to that though.  There are [many such dehumidifers](https://www.google.com/search?q=electrostatic%20air%20filter%20dehumidifier&safe=off&source=univ&tbm=shop&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=-vWLUv6vDYqPiAK5o4DwBg&sqi=2&ved=0CD8Qsxg&biw=1760&bih=988).  However, there is some danger that oxygen could be depleted in worst case situations.

Comment: I think the most important use of a bathroom fan (if it really is a "bath" room with a bath or shower) is to remove moisture. Odor removal is secondary. I don't believe any common electrostatic air cleaners act as a dehumidifier.